# Rotate Texture in function of player position

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm making a 2d game that consists in a plane fighting against spaceships trough missiles, i want the spaceships to rotate in function of the player position, so that they are always facing the player with the "head". The player can move freely in the y and x directions.
THe player and the spaceships have a Vector2 pos variable, that corresponds to their actual position.
Any help would be appreciated.

This is my (now working) code:

```
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    Vector2 temp = new Vector2();
    float angle = temp.set(entityManager.getPlayer().pos).sub(pos).angle();
    TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture);
    sb.draw(region, pos.x, pos.y, 0, 0, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight(), 1.0f, 1.0f,angle+90);
}
```

The enemy spaceships rotate, but they dont always face the player:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @dwn's answer is mathematically correct, but when you deal with LibGDX framework it's better to use native tools.

If you have positions of enemy and player storing in `Vector2`s then you may perform computations a bit convenient.
For example, to determine angle between specific enemy and player:

```
Vector2 enemyPos;
Vector2 playerPos;
Vector2 temp;

float angle = temp
                .set(playerPos)
                .sub(enemyPos)
                .angle();
```

This will give you exactly what you want. Of course it's better to keep `temp` vector in somewhere in public space to use it in such numerous calculations. You better to check other convenient `Vector2`methods, it will seriously easy your life.

Good luck.

Comment: how should i apply the angle, to make the rotation?

Comment: First of all you should not to instantiate Sprite inside every render() call. Create it once and keep it for every unit in your game separately.

You can apply some transformation parameters to every Sprite. Like rotation, scaling... And then, just call spirte.draw(sb)

Comment: well i'm actually no using Sprites, each entity has a Vector2 pos and a texture, is there any way in doing this without using sprites?

Comment: Of course. Check longest SpriteBatch#draw(Texture...) method, it has rotation parameter.

Comment: Yes, now it rotates in function of the player position, the only problem was that i must add 90 degrees to the rotation because my original texture is pointing down and it should be pointing to the right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Set..

```
v = centerPosOfShip - centerPosOfUFO
```

Normalize...

```
v /= sqrt( v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y )
```

So now we can say v = [ cos(theta)  sin(theta) ]; the rotation matrix is...

```
[ cos(theta)  -sin(theta) ]
[ sin(theta)   cos(theta) ]
```

So we can write in terms of v-components...

```
[ v.x  -v.y    centerPosOfUFO.x ][x]
[ v.y   v.x    centerPosOfUFO.y ][y]
[ 0     0      1                ][1]
```

where [x y] is any point on the UFO relative to its center.

Hope that makes sense