# Animating object angle to target angle

Tags: java, point, angle, animated

I am working on programming a game. In this game, there is an object that needs to rotate to face another object.

### Code:

Here is what I have done:

```
//targetAngle is defined to be the angle pointing towards the other object
//angle is the angle of this object
angle += 0.05 * (targetAngle - angle);
```

### Problem:

This works very well, but the object often rotates in a very indirect rout. For example, if the object was facing 3 o'clock and needed to face five o'clock, the object might travel in a counter-clockwise direction instead of a more desired clockwise direction.

I would like to make the object rotate in the most direct way possible. Any ideas on how to do this?

**Thank you for your time and input.** *If you vote down, please tell me why so I can improve this question.*

*Note, I am using radians in this program.*

Comment: Are you sure targetAngle always greater than angle? Maybe negative difference causing the problem.

Comment: @JunedAhsan No, in fact I am sure that sometimes the `angle` is sometimes greater than the `targetAngle`. I'll try to eliminate negative difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one way would be something like ...

```
dAngle = (targetAngle - angle) % two_pi; //Range of (-two_pi .. two_pi)
dAngle += (dAngle > pi? -two_pi : dAngle < -pi? two_pi : 0); //Range of [-pi .. pi]
angle += 0.05 * dAngle;
```

Also, if you want it always to face a player, but don't know the correct angle, look at ...
[Rotate Texture in function of player position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671908/rotate-texture-in-function-of-player-position/27672639#27672639)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out. Also, I am currently using this formula to find the angle: `atan2(y1-y2, x1-x2)`

Comment: That's a fine way to do it. To be performance obsessive its good to avoid inverse trig functions and reapplication of trig functions, but there's nothing wrong at all with getting an angle first, and it may give you more leverage for making animations.

Comment: First of all, your solution works like a charm! +1 and accept. Also, what is so bad about using inverse trig functions?

Comment: ! Great :D ! Probably nothing is wrong at all, for your case, so don't worry about it. There can be 3 advantages to using vectors directly instead of inv trig funcs: (1) More straightforward, because you get the basis directly, without first getting an angle, converting back to sin(angle), cos(angle), and then forming your transform basis (2) Inv trig funcs are slow (3) Some inverse trig functions introduce error into the floating-point values, which can sometimes matter if your program has a large range of high-precision values, and has tight tolerances for comparison of numbers

Comment: Just in case you want to see, the java `atan2` is on line 591 here [http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/StrictMath-source.html](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/StrictMath-source.html)